# How to deploy heroku app with secret yaml configuration file without committing the file?

Tags: deployment, heroku, yaml, config

In other rails projects, I'd have a local database.yml and in source code repository only commit the database.sample file.  When deploying, a capistrano script that would symlink a shared version of database.yml to all the releases.

When deploying to heroku, git is used and they seem to override database.yml altogether and do something internal.

That's all fine and good for database.yml, but what if I have s3 configurations in config/s3.yml.  And I'm putting my project on github so I don't want to commit the s3.yml where everyone can see my credentials.  It'd rather commit a sample s3.sample which people will override with their own settings, and keep a local s3.yml file uncommitted in my working directory.

what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but some may find this alternative useful. One work-around is to upload to bitbucket, where repos are private, and include the secret keys directly in the yml file. No need for other moving parts/gems and any potential issues there also. A longer term solution should be to configure environment variables and hide secret keys from the secrets.yml file. But if someone was in a pinch for time like I was, this is a good temporary solution.

Comment: Create a new local branch where you modify .gitignore to allow secret to be push to heroku. Don't push that branch to your Github repo

Comment: Checkout my answer for more details

Comment: Do NOT push your `secrets.yml` to Heroku EVER. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26541742/6594668

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Heroku have some guidance on this -

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: That article sucks. Not helpful.

Comment: It's important have config vars, but if we use secrets.yaml we can commit and is from there that the config is catch. But I can push secrets to my repo, because in my case is a public repo.

Comment: Thats a wonderful way to do that, but isn't that stressful, having to fix that by hand across, multiple deployments?

Answer (score 13):

An alternative solution is to create a new **local-branch** where you modify .gitignore so **secret-file** can be pushed to heroku.
**DON'T** push this branch to your Github repo.

To push non-master branch to heroku, use:

```
git push heroku secret-branch:master
```

More info can be found on:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#advanced-linking-local-branches-to-remote-apps

Use `heroku run bash` and then `ls` to check whether your secret-file have been pushed on to heroku or not

Comment: I like this answer much more since heroku config vars cannot contain whole files.

Answer (score 7):

Store the s3 credentials in environment variables.

```
$ cd myapp
$ heroku config:add S3_KEY=8N029N81 S3_SECRET=9s83109d3+583493190
Adding config vars:
  S3_KEY    => 8N029N81
  S3_SECRET => 9s83109d3+583493190
Restarting app...done.
```

In your app:

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
  :access_key_id     => ENV['S3_KEY'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
)
```

See the Heroku [Config Vars documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) which explain development setup etc.

Comment: "In your app:"

where in my app????

What if you're not using amazonS3? does heroku use amazonS3, is that this tells you to use it? Questions like these are missing in the guides. I really don't understand how people just understand these guides. They don't help me.

The guide talks about a procfile. I have no procfile. -_-

Comment: Saved my life! But I thought placing secret keys in application.yml and masking with gems like Figaro will be enough to let Heroku access them?

Answer (score 7):

If using Rails 4.1 beta, try the heroku_secrets gem, from https://github.com/alexpeattie/heroku_secrets:

```
gem 'heroku_secrets', github: 'alexpeattie/heroku_secrets'
```

This lets you store secret keys in Rails 4.1's **config/secrets.yml** (which is not checked in to source control) and then just run

```
rake heroku:secrets RAILS_ENV=production
```

to make its contents available to heroku (it parses your secrets.yml file and pushes everything in it to heroku as environment variables, per the heroku best practice docs).

Comment: "which is not checked in to source control"

Does this means you don't have to explicitly gitignore it? when you use the passive voice like that, it leaves questions as to what the user should do. does the heroku_secrets gem handle not making it public? I've read you should not gitignore the secrets.yml file when using heroku_secrets gem. These are things to address that aren't addressed when you use phrasing like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out the **[Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)** gem.

Comment: If you are trying to do this for database settings, as per gem document, Figaro uses Rails' standard hooks to initialize. Unfortunately, this hook apparently occurs after database.yml is read. Because of this issue, environment variables created in application.yml don't work inside database.yml.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by building the credentials from env variables during the build time, and write it to where I need it to be before the slug is created.

---

Some usecase specific info that you can probably translate to your situation:

I'm deploying a Node project, and in the package.json in the `postinstall` script I call "bash create-secret.sh". Since postinstall is performed before the slug is created, the file will be added to the slug.

I had to use a bash script because I had some trouble printing strings that contained newlines that had to be printed correctly, and I wasn't able to get it done with Node. Probably just me not being skilled enough, but maybe you run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this with Heroku + Build & Deploy-time Secrets. It seems like it's not something Heroku supports. This means for a rails app, there is no way other than committing BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM for example to get from private repo.

I'll try to see if there is a way to have CI bundle private deps before beaming at heroku