# How to solve error "Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment" (Rails 4.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a Rails application, using Rails 4.1, from scratch and I am facing a strange problem that I am not able to solve.

Every time I try to deploy my application on Heroku I get an error 500:

```
Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`
```

The `secret.yml` file contains the following configuration:

```
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

On Heroku I configured the "`SECRET_KEY_BASE`" environment variable with the result of the `rake secret` command. If I launch `heroku config`, I can see the variable with the correct name and value.

Why am I still getting this error?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and would love to know why this is happening, too.  If I figure out why, I'll post back with my solution.

Comment: Is your config file called `secret.yml` or `secrets.yml`?

Comment: I configured again the .gitignore file with the one generated by rails and now everything works fine

Comment: We also had this issue when we upgraded to Rails 4.  In our case, it was because we had a custom environment name, and that wasn't reflected in secrets.yml.  I just had to add a line to the file with the non-standard name, commit, and re-deploy.

Comment: For future readers: this answer is probably the easiest and most accurate: stackoverflow.com/a/26541742/4880924

Answer (score 233, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by creating an environment variable to be loaded every time I logged in to the production server, and made a [mini-guide](https://gist.github.com/pablosalgadom/4d75f30517edc6230a67) of the steps to configure it:

I was using Rails 4.1 with Unicorn v4.8.2 and when I tried to deploy my application it didn't start properly and in the `unicorn.log` file I found this error message:

```
app error: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)
```

After some research I found out that Rails 4.1 changed the way to manage the `secret_key`, so if you read the `secrets.yml` file located at `exampleRailsProject/config/secrets.yml` you'll find something like this:

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

This means that Rails recommends you to use an environment variable for the `secret_key_base` in your production server. In order to solve this error you should follow these steps to create an environment variable for Linux (in my case Ubuntu) in your production server:

1. In the terminal of your production server execute:

   ```
   $ RAILS_ENV=production rake secret
   ```

   This returns a large string with letters and numbers. Copy that, which we will refer to that code as `GENERATED_CODE`.
2. Login to your server

   - If you login as the root user, find this file and edit it:

     ```
     $ vi /etc/profile
     ```

     Go to the bottom of the file using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (capital "G") in vi.

     Write your environment variable with the `GENERATED_CODE`, pressing <kbd>i</kbd> to insert in vi. Be sure to be in a new line at the end of the file:

     ```
     $ export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
     ```

     Save the changes and close the file using <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then "`:x`" and <kbd>Enter</kbd> for save and exit in vi.
   - But if you login as normal user, let's call it "`example_user`" for this gist, you will need to find one of these other files:

     ```
     $ vi ~/.bash_profile
     $ vi ~/.bash_login
     $ vi ~/.profile
     ```

     These files are in order of importance, which means that if you have the first file, then you wouldn't need to edit the others. If you found these two files in your directory `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` you only will have to write in the first one `~/.bash_profile`, because Linux will read only this one and the other will be ignored.

     Then we go to the bottom of the file using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> again  and write the environment variable with our `GENERATED_CODE` using  <kbd>i</kbd> again, and be sure add a new line at the end of the file:

     ```
     $ export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
     ```

     Having written the code, save the changes and close the file using <kbd>Esc</kbd> again and "`:x`" and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit.
3. You can verify that our environment variable is properly set in Linux with this command:

   ```
   $ printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE
   ```

   or with:

   ```
   $ echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE
   ```

   When you execute this command, if everything went ok, it will show you the `GENERATED_CODE` from before. Finally with all the configuration done you should be able to deploy without problems your Rails application with Unicorn or some other tool.

When you close your shell and login again to the production server you will have this environment variable set and ready to use it.

And that's it! I hope this [mini-guide](https://gist.github.com/pablosalgadom/4d75f30517edc6230a67) helps you solve this error.

Disclaimer: I'm not a Linux or Rails guru, so if you find something wrong or any error I will be glad to fix it.

Comment: It seems, that Rails does't sees environment variable SECRET_KEY_BASE. printenv shows it, rails c production also displays it, if I inspect ENV. But, i has no effect, when I restarting Unicorn. The only way, that works now, is pasting it directly to secrets.yml

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for your full explanation. I just learned that there are gem that exist for managing an app's environment variables. 'Dotenv' is one and 'foreman' for heroku. While it was education to fix the error manually this way, maybe using one of those gems will streamline the process?

Comment: I'm glad that my answer was helpful, thanks for the gem options @ninja08, they definitively make the process easier, mainly for those who use capistrano or other incremental tool to manage the server :)

Comment: Following Demi Magus's excellent instructions, I did something like this:
cd /var/www/rails;
rvm use ext-rbx-2.5.2@rails;
SKB_FILE=/var/www/.secret_key_base;
echo "export SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(RAILS_ENV=production rake secret)" > $SKB_FILE;
. $SKB_FILE;
echo ". $SKB_FILE" | tee -a ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile;
chmod o-rwx $SKB_FILE;

Comment: Nice answer!! I not know why this not is solved for me, i create question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117318/missing-secret-token-and-secret-key-base-for-production-environment

Comment: you can use figaro gem https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro to handle environment variables within your rails app.

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove RAILS_ENV=production in my remote Ubuntu environment and run `bundle exec rake secret`.

Comment: I LOVE you so much, this fixed my problem <3 <3 <3

Comment: I have to log out and then login in order to see anything in `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` after modifying `/etc/profile`

Comment: Note that

`echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` can show a value and still not actually be available to the ruby process.

`printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE` is what you need to check. The first will still have results if it's only a local value and not exported.

If need to load and export a file, you need to do what's here (this is for bash) http://stackoverflow.com/a/30969768/1053377 No, `. .env` or `source .env` will not export them for the child process by default.

Comment: After implementing this step the server stops responding to requests, even curl requests from the server itself. Tried several times and every time after the key is added the puma server stops responding to requests, though it shows as running.

Comment: One note: After you edit the /etc/profile and one of the 3 other profiles, I had to reboot my terminal for it to appear for either `printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE` or `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE`.

Comment: For future readers: The answer below is 100% easier and basically does the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26541742/4880924

Answer (score 96):

I'm going to assume that you do not have your `secrets.yml` checked into source control (ie. it's in the `.gitignore` file).  Even if this isn't your situation, it's what many other people viewing this question have done because they have their code exposed on Github and don't want their secret key floating around.

If it's not in source control, Heroku doesn't know about it.  So Rails is looking for `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` and it hasn't been set because Rails sets it by checking the `secrets.yml` file which doesn't exist.  The simple workaround is to go into your `config/environments/production.rb` file and add the following line:

```
Rails.application.configure do
    ...
    config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
    ...
end
```

This tells your application to set the secret key using the environment variable instead of looking for it in `secrets.yml`.  It would have saved me a lot of time to know this up front.

Comment: This is the best answer. `Figaro` and `heroku_secrets` don't do anything unless Rails knows that `SECRET_KEY_BASE` lives in `ENV`. I've been struggling with this thinking that if the config var existed on Heroku, Rails would pick it up just by virtue of it existing, but now it seems blindingly obvious that Rails would need to know where to look.

I've been wondering how I can have code on Github without having to worry about the secret key base thing; now I know.

Comment: Agreed, I think the secrets.yml is superfluous with great gems like Figaro.

Comment: Seems like the best option if you use github and heroku for your project.

Comment: What's wrong with committing your secrets.yml with `production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`. Won't that also mean the actual secret key is not exposed. Is there risk to exposing dev and test keys in committed secrets.yml if it is all just seed and test data?

Comment: This works even in Rails 6.0.2, when there is no secrets.yml any more.

Answer (score 51):

Add `config/secrets.yml` to version control and deploy again.  You might need to remove a line from `.gitignore` so that you can commit the file.

I had this exact same issue and it just turned out that the boilerplate `.gitignore` Github created for my Rails application included `config/secrets.yml`.

Comment: should this be the new default for the gitignore? I just figure the Current version should be assumed and previous versions' adjustments described in the gitignore.

Comment: As long as you never commit production configuration information to your version control you're good.  Use your own judgement.  AFAIK, the boilerplate `config/secrets.yml` is safe.

Comment: config/secrets.yml should NEVER be in the repo you can do.yml.sample and fill it in with fake data but for security, never do .yml in repos

Comment: @user3379926, within the context of a Rails app on Heroku, you can't pick and choose which files are included in version control and which are not.  Rails 4.1 expects the secret configuration to exist otherwise the application will not run.  If you have a way to resolve the issue posed in the Question above without resorting to committing the secrets.yml file in Git, please help improve this thread by providing that advice.

Comment: @danielricecodes you can manually set the value in an initializer. Something like `Rails.application.config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` would work and remove the error without adding `secrets.yml` to source.

Comment: @user3379926: When I generate a new Rails application with `rails new` (producing, in this case, a Gemfile whose `rails` gem has the version `4.2.4`), the file `config/secrets.yml` is generated. It includes pregenerated secret keys for the development and test environments, and reads the secretkey for the production environment from an environment variable: `secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`. Seems to me that it's perfectly safe, and indeed useful, to keep this `secrets.yml` file in version control, provided one never actually defines the secret key there.

Comment: user3379926 mentioned, you should never check in your secrets.yml into your git repo, for future stackoverflow users consider changing this as the accepted answer, as it is not safe or accepted practice.

Comment: @jasonleonhard why? if you're reading the secret key from env vars anyway, what's the big deal? there's no secrets being exposed.

Comment: @user3379926 Tracking secrets.yml isn't a bad thing unless you put your actual secret values in it.  Below Demi Magus shows a way to do this safely by using `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me.

SSH into your production server and `cd` into your current directory, run `bundle exec rake secret` or `rake secret`, you will get a long string as an output, copy that string.

Now run `sudo nano /etc/environment`.

Paste at the bottom of the file

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=rake secret
ruby -e 'p ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]'
```

Where `rake secret` is the string you just copied, paste that copied string in place of `rake secret`.

Restart the server and test by running `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE`.

Answer (score 3):

While you can use initializers like the other answers, the conventional Rails 4.1+ way is to use the `config/secrets.yml`. The reason for the Rails team to introduce this is beyond the scope of this answer but the TL;DR is that `secret_token.rb` conflates configuration and code as well as being a security risk since the token is checked into source control history and the only system that needs to know the production secret token is the production infrastructure.

You should add this file to `.gitignore` much like you wouldn't add `config/database.yml` to source control either.

Referencing Heroku's own code for setting up `config/database.yml` from `DATABASE_URL` in their [Buildpack for Ruby](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby), I ended up [forking their repo](https://github.com/VerdigrisTech/heroku-buildpack-ruby) and modified it to create `config/secrets.yml` from `SECRETS_KEY_BASE` environment variable.

Since this feature was introduced in Rails 4.1, I felt it was appropriate to edit `./lib/language_pack/rails41.rb` and add this functionality.

The following is the [snippet](https://github.com/VerdigrisTech/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/master/lib/language_pack/rails41.rb#L33-50) from the modified buildpack I created at my company:

```
class LanguagePack::Rails41 < LanguagePack::Rails4

  # ...

  def compile
    instrument "rails41.compile" do
      super
      allow_git do
        create_secrets_yml
      end
    end
  end

  # ...

  # writes ERB based secrets.yml for Rails 4.1+
  def create_secrets_yml
    instrument 'ruby.create_secrets_yml' do
      log("create_secrets_yml") do
        return unless File.directory?("config")
        topic("Writing config/secrets.yml to read from SECRET_KEY_BASE")
        File.open("config/secrets.yml", "w") do |file|
          file.puts <<-SECRETS_YML
<%
raise "No RACK_ENV or RAILS_ENV found" unless ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"]
%>

<%= ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] %>:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
          SECRETS_YML
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # ...

end
```

You can of course extend this code to add other secrets (e.g. third party API keys, etc.) to be read off of your environment variable:

```
...
<%= ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] %>:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  third_party_api_key: <%= ENV["THIRD_PARTY_API"] %>
```

This way, you can access this secret in a very standard way:

```
Rails.application.secrets.third_party_api_key
```

Before redeploying your app, be sure to set your environment variable first:
[image: Setting SECRET_KEY_BASE in Heroku Dashboard]

Then add your modified buildpack (or you're more than welcome to link to mine) to your Heroku app (see Heroku's [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)) and redeploy your app.

The buildpack will automatically create your `config/secrets.yml` from your environment variable as part of the dyno build process every time you `git push` to Heroku.

EDIT: Heroku's own [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/426) suggests creating `config/secrets.yml` to read from the environment variable but this implies you should check this file into source control. In my case, this doesn't work well since I have hardcoded secrets for development and testing environments that I'd rather not check in.

Comment: While a great solution the .dotenv and .foreman gems solve this problem: "I have hardcoded secrets for development and testing environments" - so using those gems means you do not need the buildpack as you can use ENV_VAR in your secrets file for dev and test also

Comment: Note that environment variables are logged by most infrastructure, which means unencrypted environment variables will be in plain text in the logs. I do not use Heroku for my Rails apps, so have no recommendation for it, but with AWS we pull encrypted values from Parameter Store during build from inside the build container and unencrypt them to populate these kinds of secure assets.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the secret keys to as environment variables on the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` of your server:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
```

And then, you can source your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
source ~/.bashrc 
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**Never commit your secrets.yml**

Answer (score 2):

For rails6, I was facing the same problem as I was missing the following files. Once I added them the issue was resolved:

```
1. config/master.key
2. config/credentials.yml.enc
```

Make sure you have these files!

Comment: You should not version your master.key file, since that contains the key to decrypt your credentials encrypted file

Answer (score 0):

What I did :
On my production server, I create a config file (confthin.yml) for Thin (I'm using it) and add the following information :

```
environment: production
user: www-data
group: www-data
SECRET_KEY_BASE: mysecretkeyproduction
```

I then launch the app with

```
thin start -C /whereeveristhefieonprod/configthin.yml
```

Work like a charm and then no need to have the secret key on version control

Hope it could help, but I'm sure the same thing could be done with Unicorn and others.

Comment: can you explain why/how this is working? The question was for heroku. Is thin an alternative, or is it compatible with heroku?

Answer (score -1):

I have a patch that I've used in a Rails 4.1 app to let me continue using the legacy key generator (and hence backwards session compatibility with Rails 3), by allowing the secret_key_base to be blank.

```
Rails::Application.class_eval do
  # the key_generator will then use ActiveSupport::LegacyKeyGenerator.new(config.secret_token)
  fail "I'm sorry, Dave, there's no :validate_secret_key_config!" unless instance_method(:validate_secret_key_config!)
  def validate_secret_key_config! #:nodoc:
    config.secret_token = secrets.secret_token
    if config.secret_token.blank?
      raise "Missing `secret_token` for '#{Rails.env}' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`"
    end 
  end 
end
```

I've since reformatted the patch are [submitted it to Rails as a Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16535)

Answer (score -1):

I've created `config/initializers/secret_key.rb` file and I wrote only following line of code:

```
Rails.application.config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

But I think that solution posted by [@Erik Trautman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26541742/568838) is more elegant ;)

Edit:
Oh, and finally I found this advice on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/426 :)

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

this is works good https://gist.github.com/pablosalgadom/4d75f30517edc6230a67
for root user should edit

```
$ /etc/profile
```

but if you non root should put the generate code in the following

```
$ ~/.bash_profile

$ ~/.bash_login

$ ~/.profile
```

Answer (score -1):

On Nginx/Passenger/Ruby (2.4)/Rails (5.1.1) nothing else worked except:

`passenger_env_var` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` in the server block.

Source: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_env_var

Answer (score -1):

Demi Magus answer worked for me until Rails 5.

On Apache2/Passenger/Ruby (2.4)/Rails (5.1.6), I had to put

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

from Demi Magus answer in /etc/apache2/envvars, cause /etc/profile seems to be ignored.

Source: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html#apache

Answer (score -3):

In my case, the problem was that `config/master.key` was not in version control, and I had created the project on a different computer.

The default .gitignore that Rails creates excludes this file. Since it's impossible to deploy without having this file, it needs to be in version control, in order to be able to deploy from any team member's computer.

Solution: remove the `config/master.key` line from `.gitignore`, commit the file from the computer where the project was created, and now you can `git pull` on the other computer and deploy from it.

People are saying not to commit some of these files to version control, without offering an alternative solution. As long as you're not working on an open source project, I see no reason not to commit everything that's required to run the project, including credentials.

Comment: Never commit your master key file to git. This is a giant security vulnerability for your app. For open source it's tough, but creating a password vault with your preferred password manager is a better option.

Comment: You set the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable in production. Your answer is very wrong (according to the Rails documentation) and leads to an insecure condition. Please update it or remove it.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty Please elaborate. What is the "insecure condition", and how should we avoid it?

Comment: Just like @wsizoo. Committing the master key to version control is insecure and should not be done. It's in the `.gitignore` file for a very good reason. Share the file via _other means_ for development. Follow 12-factor-app principles and place it in the environment for production. _Especially_ for an open-source project, the master key in production should not be shared with the world.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty Like I said, "as long as you're not working on an open source project".

Comment: @RobinDaugherty I'm still waiting for you to explain what the "insecure condition" is.

Comment: @AndrewKoster the insecure condition is having a secret committed to source control. There is no situation where committing the secret to source control is correct or safe. Rails 7 documentation says to set `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable to solve your specific issue. Older versions of Rails required additional steps to use the environment variable, but none required committing the secret key to source control.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty In a proprietary code base, the entire contents of the repository are secret. So you're saying not to put secrets with other secrets but I don't see why not.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem after I used the .gitignore file from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore

Everything worked out fine after I commented the following lines in the .gitignore file.

```
config/initializers/secret_token.rb
config/secrets.yml
```

Comment: As is repeated everywhere, committing secrets.yml or secret_token.rb to git is NOT recommended.

Comment: @cofiem People are allowed to use working solutions that you don't personally recommend.