# 500 internal server error after deploying rails app Rail 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4.1

So this issue is pretty straight forward:

```
** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`) (process 31929, thread 0x95116e4(Worker 1))
```

So I did that, I went and added the secrets.yml file to the `appname/current/config/` directory and added:

```
production:
    secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And then I restarted the server.

Still I get this 500 error and still the error.log sais that I am missing this file. Am I missing some basic step here?

Note: This is running with passenger and apache2

Comment: should it be indented so much? `secret_key_base`

Comment: its indented by two, but when I was doing it here I indented it by four .... I dont think indentation matters in the grand scheme of things

Comment: Check this. Looks to be similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180650/how-to-solve-error-missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment-on-h