# Getting Puma Postgres Server to Work in Development to Cooperate with Heroku, or does going back to Sqlite make sense?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, puma

I got using `puma` instead of `rails s` to work fine for awhile, but then while developing and making code changes and refreshing at some point the refresh wasn't working, delaying for a long time. I assumed it had crashed or something, so I killed the puma server, but then it said 'gracefully shutting down' for several minutes so I killed the terminal window. Then, in a new window when I tried to use `puma` it said the host was already taken, so the process was still running. Unable to find where it was, I restarted my computer. Upon restart, I now get the error `An unhandled lowlevel error occured. The application logs may have details.` or `PG::ConnectionBad fe_sendauth: no password supplied`, depending on whether I run `puma` or `RAILS_ENV=development puma`.

Neither of these responses seem to make sense, and this error I see others having on `rake db:migrate`. So I tried migrating the database and got the same error `PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

And in the logs when trying to run the server: `Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing`secret_key_base`for 'production' environment, set this value in`config/secrets.yml`>`

Now this makes the least sense to me, as why is `puma` running production environment by default and requiring a special command to run in development?

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Is dependent on Heroku to pass the secret_key_base is my assumption, so it doesn't work for development. But then even `RAILS_ENV=development puma` throws

```
PG::ConnectionBad
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

And a trace that doesn't appear to help me:

```
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/Users/lasernite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/Users/lasernite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:388:in `check_pending!'
activerecord (4.1.7) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
rack-timeout (0.2.0) lib/rack/timeout.rb:108:in `call'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.7) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:82:in `call'
puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
puma (2.11.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I'm stuck on where to try and resolve this error.

Please give any insight you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your "`config/secrets.yml`" file listed in `.gitignore`?  `Heroku` needs that file.  Remove or comment it out from `.gitignore`.  I had the same problem and that was my issue.

Also, see this post for the same answer:
[How to solve error "Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment" (Rails 4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180650/how-to-solve-error-missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment-on-h)

Good luck!

Comment: Make sure you have put your secret_key_base in an environment variable before you take your secrets.yml file out of .gitignore