# Rails Rubber secret_key_base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

Kind of pulling my hair out here.
Other than hard coding the secret_key_base into secrets.yml, I cannot figure out a way to get it into my Rails 4.1 app running on Ubuntu 14 and deployed via the Rubber gem using unicorn and nginx.

I have tried the following
in `secrets.yml`:

`production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`

and in my `/etc/environment`:

`export SECRET_KEY_BASE=ivegotalovelybunchofcoconuts`

That gives me:
`app error: Missing secret_token and secret_key_base for 'production' environment, set these values in config/secrets.yml`

I tried the figaro gem and put this into my `application.rb`

`config.secret_key_base = Figaro.env.SECRET_KEY_BASE`

Same error.

If I launch a console I can see the variables no problem:

`irb(main):004:0> Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base
=> "ivegotalovelybunchofcoconuts"
irb(main):005:0> Figaro.env.SECRET_KEY_BASE
=> "ivegotalovelybunchofcoconuts"`

Comment: Did you set secret_token too? I see rails complains about it, too. Maybe the message is generic and complains about both even thought one is available?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180650/how-to-solve-error-missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment-on-h

Comment: I have written a page to output the values and I can see that in the Unicorn running version (i.e. not console) that the values are blank. It is not picking up things from the environment. And yes Nitin I found that page. That is why all of my examples of what I have done are from there. It didn't work.