# Rails - Disabling secrets.yml for api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There doesn't seem to be a configuration option for the `secrets.yml` check even if I am running Rails as a JSON API

Puma caught this error:

> Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production'
>   environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)

Any clue what to do? I suppose I can generate a dummy `secret_key_base` and move on

Comment: are you sure the `secrets.yml` file is present in your production environment? [This SO suggests git might have ignored it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23206010/3035830).

Comment: Okay - to be clear. I don't want to use the secrets.yml - this is a JSON api server

Answer (score 0):

As of 8 March 2022

According to [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32413#issuecomment-482626614) the Rails GitHub project, there is supposed to be a way to disable it but it still isn't working.

[This comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32413#issuecomment-724628696) mentions how they're **supposed** to be disabled but that is currently not working.

```rb
config.require_master_key = false
config.read_encrypted_secrets = false
```

As far as I could find, your only option is to provide dummy values at the moment.