# Production log file is not updating, Rails 4.16 + Passanger

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails 4.1.6 app on Passanger (Shared host).

Quite a while I worked in development, but now I switched to **production**.

In environment.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
```

then `touch tmp/restart.txt` to restart server.

When accessing my app I am receiving **Internal Server Error**. It is ok. I expected that, so I went to **production.log** to see what caused error, but it was blank.

Before I switched to production, development.log file showed all logs without problem.

**What I tried:**

1) Deleted production.log  and restarted server. After folder reload production.log was created again. Permisions: 0664 the same as development.log

2) Added lines and restarted server :

```
      config.log_level = :debug
      RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new('log/production.log')
```

3) Double checked if current environment is production.

4) Manually wrote in production.log using console command:

```
Rails.logger.error('TEST ERROR')
```

After this command I saw this error message in production.log file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem.

Bassically, there wasn't any problem with production.log , problem was that my Rails 4 app didn't really start. I received Apache error:

```
Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`
```

So I solved above error with help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26172408/1460362)

And now Rails 4 app starts and production.log updates without problem.