# SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars set too late - Can't start Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

RuntimeError, missing secret_key_base when starting a Rails app on Heroku.
I've already added the secret as a ENV var and looking at the logs it feels that Heroku is setting it up too late.
Has something similar happened to you? How would you recommend approaching this?

```
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469373+00:00 app[web.1]: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469375+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:513:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469376+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469377+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:521:in `build_request'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469377+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:693:in `build_request'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469378+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469379+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469379+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469380+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469381+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469381+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'
2016-12-18T01:57:34.469382+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
2016-12-18T02:32:44.013101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-12-18T02:32:43.362607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-12-18T02:32:43.362607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-12-18T02:32:44.038208+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2016-12-18T02:32:44.038778+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2016-12-18T02:32:44.038774+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2016-12-18 02:32:44 +0000 ===
2016-12-18T02:32:44.039352+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-12-18T02:32:44.259020+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-12-18T09:45:45.086929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-12-18T09:45:44.933284+00:00 app[api]: Set SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by user XXX@gmail.com
2016-12-18T09:45:44.933284+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user XXX@gmail.com
```

Comment: Its actually happening as the first thing on a reboot. Thats why it says `State changed from down to starting`. I don't think I ever have had to manually set `SECRET_KEY_BASE` - Heroku sets this as well as bunch of other env vars when it detects that you have pushed a rails app.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198952/missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment-error-on-heroku?noredirect=1#comment69598253_41198952) might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got fixed by removing `config/secrets.yml` from the `.gitignore`.